# Hibernate join fetch with conditions for the right side of the join

Tags: hibernate, join, inner-join

I've got following named query written in HQL:

```
query = "select u from User u " +
   "join fetch u.devices d " +
   "join fetch u.ipRestrictions ir " +
   "join fetch u.employees e where " +
   "u.login = :login and " +
   "u.enumDataState.id = :dataStateId and " +
   "d.enumDataState.id = :dataStateId and " +
   "ir.enumDataState.id = :dataStateId and " +
   "e.enumDataState.id = :dataStateId ")
```

When I execute it I pass an email and dataStateId value. I can see in the database table, that there is a user with the given email and dataStateId, but I do not get any result.

The purpose of the query is to `join fetch` the active user (dataStateId tells if the user is active or not) with the given email with devices, ipRestrictions and employees which are also active.

I already saw some answers on stackoverflow, some suggested to use `left join fetch` but the `left join fetch` didn't work either.

I am sure, that there is a user with the given email and the given dataStateId, because I can see him in the database data editor.

How can I solve this here? It's a huge problem, because I will have a lot of such functions where I need to check the right side of the `join fetch` using some condition.

I am using Hibernate v5.2.

Comment: your query specify that you're looking for a user 'login' with user status / device status / iprestriction status / employee status  all at the same time at the same status you give. You sure your dataset have such user ? (you only speak about user and user status not the other.)

Comment: The query has to return the user where email and status match, and optionally other objects where status is also active. So if there is a matching user but it doesn't have any matching devices I want to get the user anyway but with empty devices list. I am using the join fetches to avoid the 1+n queries problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your comment, you should use :

```
select u from User u
    left join fetch u.devices d 
    left join fetch u.ipRestrictions ir
    left join fetch u.employees e 
where 
    u.login = :login and u.enumDataState.id = :dataStateId and 
    (d is null or d.enumDataState.id = :dataStateId) and 
    (ir is null or ir.enumDataState.id = :dataStateId) and
    (e is null or e.enumDataState.id = :dataStateId)
```

Note: the `is null` may not work (depends on JPA version and implementation). 
You may need to use

- u.devices is null
- u.devices is empty